# Finding $\operatorname{Var}(X(Y+Z))$ where $(X,Y,Z)$ has a normal distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, expected-value, variance

I have a task:

> Random Variable $(X,Y,Z)$ has normal distribution with expected value $EX=0, EY=EZ=1$ and covariance matrix:
>   $$\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
> 1&1&0\\
> 1&2&1\\
> 0&1&2\end{array}\right].$$
>   Calculate $\operatorname{Var}(X(Y+Z))$

From this I know, that $X,Z$ are independent and $$EX^2=1, EXY=1,EY^2=3, EYZ=2,EZ^2=3$$

Simplify $$\operatorname{Var}(X(Y+Z))=E(X(Y+Z))^2-(EX(Y+Z))^2$$
I don't know how calculate $E(X(Y+Z))^2$.
Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: How about using $Var(XY+XZ)=Var(XY)+Var(XZ)+2Cov(XY,XZ)$?

Comment: @StubbornAtom Сalculating the covariance, we come across the expression $\mathbb E[X^2YZ]$ which is not much better than $\mathbb E[X^2Y^2]$ and the others appeared in $\mathbb E(X(Y+Z))^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that
$$
\Sigma = \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1&1&0\\
1&2&1\\
0&1&2\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1&0&0\\
1&1&0\\
0&1&1\end{array}\right)\,\cdot \, \left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1&0&0\\
1&1&0\\
0&1&1\end{array}\right)^T = BB^T,
$$
You can transform the vector $(X,Y,Z)^T$ into a vector $(U,V,W)^T$ consisting of independent standard normal random variables by
$$
B^{-1}\cdot\pmatrix{X\cr Y-1\cr Z-1} =  \pmatrix{U\cr V\cr W}  
$$
Then 
$$
\pmatrix{X\cr Y-1\cr Z-1} =B\cdot  \pmatrix{U\cr V\cr W} = \pmatrix{U\cr U+V\cr V+W}
$$
So we can replace $X=U$, $Y=U+V+1$, $Z=V+W+1$ and therefore 
$$
X(Y+Z) = U(U+2V+W+2)=U(U+T)
$$
where $U$ and $T$ are independent, $U\sim \mathcal N(0,1)$, $T=2V+W+2\sim\mathcal N(2,5)$. 
So 
$$
\mathbb E[X^2(Y+Z)^2] = \mathbb E[U^2(U^2+2UT+T^2)] 
$$
$$= \underbrace{\mathbb E[U^4]}_3+2\underbrace{\mathbb E[U^3]}_0\cdot\mathbb E[T] + \underbrace{\mathbb E[U^2]}_1\cdot\underbrace{\mathbb E[T^2]}_9 = 12.
$$

Comment: Thank you, but I don't understand this transormation. Why in this way we transform $(X,Y,Z)$ on independent standard normal random variables $(U,V,W)$?

Comment: Covariance matrix of $\pmatrix{U\\ V\\ W}$ is identity matrix $I$. The covariance matrix of $B\pmatrix{U\\ V\\ W}$ is $B\cdot I \cdot B^T=\Sigma$, so this transform leads to the vector with given covariance matrix.

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand :)

Comment: Good! In addition: This is exactly the statement from here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Normal_random_vector, where my $B$ is denoted by $A$.